# Why does String creation using `newInstance()` method behave different when using `var` compared to using explicit type `String`?

Tags: java, reflection, string-pool

I am learning about reflection in Java. By accident, I discovered the following, for me unexpected behavior.

Both tests as written below succeed.

```java
class NewInstanceUsingReflection {
    @Test
    void testClassNewInstance()
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        final var input = "A string";
        final var theClass = input.getClass();
        final var constructor = theClass.getConstructor();
        final String newString = constructor.newInstance();

        assertEquals("", newString);
    }

    @Test
    void testClassNewInstanceWithVarOnly()
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        final var input = "A string";
        final var theClass = input.getClass();
        final var constructor = theClass.getConstructor();
        final var newString = constructor.newInstance();

        assertEquals("A string", newString);
    }
}
```

The only difference apart from the assertion is that the **`newString`** variable type is explicit in the first test and declared as `var` in the second test.

I'm using java 17 and the junit5 test framework.

Why is the value of `newString` an empty string in the first test and the `input` string value in the second test?

Does it have something todo with the string-pool?

Or is something else going on?

Comment: Strangely, in the case where `newString` is `var`, you get "A string" only if `input` is `final`.

Comment: Hmm... very strange... [here (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/yr5wgA) is a Java 11 version, without JUnit's `assertEquals(...)`, showing the same behaviour.

Comment: Also added @rgettman's observation to this test case.

Comment: according to the bug report analysis, it sounds like the bug is that `input` has an internal type like `constant string "A string"` (which helps optimizations) instead of just `String`. Then, the compiler figures that `newString` is also an instance of `constant string "A string"`. Writing String forces it to be String type.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Java17, same problem. The explanation is clearly: bug.

decompiling it, the relevant section:

```
        20: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/Object
        23: invokevirtual #35                 // Method java/lang/reflect/Constructor.newInstance:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        26: checkcast     #41                 // class java/lang/String
        29: astore        4
        31: ldc           #23                 // String A string
        33: ldc           #23                 // String A string
        35: invokevirtual #43                 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

`astore 4` is where the result goes, which is nowhere: slot 4 is not used any further. Instead, the same string constant is loaded twice, trivially resulting in, effectively, `"A string".equals("A string")`, which is of course `true`.

Replacing `var` with String, recompiling, and rerunning `javap`:

```
        20: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/Object
        23: invokevirtual #35                 // Method java/lang/reflect/Constructor.newInstance:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        26: checkcast     #41                 // class java/lang/String
        29: astore        4
        31: ldc           #23                 // String A string
        33: aload         4
        35: invokevirtual #43                 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Identical in every way, except the second `ldc` is the correct `aload 4`.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's happening here. It feels more like the `var` is somehow causing that `ldc` to duplicate (in contrast to an analysis incorrectly thinking that the values are guaranteed to be identical; javac intentionally does very little such optimizations).

I'm having a *really* hard time figuring out how this has been in **2** LTS releases. Impressive find.

Next step is to verify on the [latest JDK (18)](https://jdk.java.net/18/), and then to [file a bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/). I did a quick look if it has been reported already, but I'm not sure what search terms to use. I didn't find any report in my search, though.

NB: The decompilation traces were produced using `javap -c -v NewInstanceUsingReflection`.

EDIT: Just tried on ecj (`Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) v20210223-0522, 3.25.0, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2020. All rights reserved.`) - bug doesn't happen there.

Comment: reproduced with Java 19 (OpenJDK) - not with Eclipse

Comment: `final var newString = "A string".getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();` yields the same result. Good find.

Comment: FTR: I have submitted a bug report to oracle. Will post the link to the issue as soon as I get it.

Comment: Good to see that this question sparks a good discussion and that it is indeed identified as a bug by the community. Thanks for submitting it to oracle Turing85 and for the analysis using decompilation rzwitserloot. I'm curious about the follow-up of the issue.

Comment: Reproduced with Java 18 (Oracle OpenJDK version 18)

Comment: Update: [Here is the bug-report (ID: JDK-8293578)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8293578)

Comment: Link for those who prefer reading JDK tickets in a JIRA interface: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8293578

Comment: As for what causes this (I think...): constants are represented in javac as types (just like they are in many other compilers). Since `getClass()` returns `Class<? extends [exact type]>`, this ends up being `Class<? extends "A string">` (the constant being the type). The constructor is then also `Constructor<? extends "A string">`, and finally `newInstance` returns a `"A string"` as a type. So the type of `newString` is the constant, which then gets turned into an LDC. The bug being in how the type for `getClass` is determined.

Comment: @JornVernee But why does `Class<"string">` have a no-arg constructor? If all const types has a no-arg constructor by default, then `Class<42>` should also have one, but it doesn't and throws `NoSuchMethodException`. If (not likely) it inherited the constructor from `String.class`, then this is also a bug.

Comment: also I found that `var newString = "foo".getClass().getConstructor().newInstance(); newString = "bar"; println(newString);` prints `foo`. Are there something wrong with the constant propagation?

Comment: @yyyy For the purpose of 'which members do you have', I bet it's just what String has, which notably includes a no-args constructor. The problem is that javac itself goes: Oh, it's an expression of type [voodoo magic here], therefore I can just load straight from the constant pool. At the bytecode level nothing special is going on (`javac` simply cooked up the 'wrong' bytecode).

Comment: @yyyy Same problem. `newString` is of type "foo constant" (which is nowhere in the spec, its a 'trick' employed by `javac`, which is being incorrectly applied here), and thus `println(newString)` is being turned into bytecode by pulling "foo" out of the constant pool, instead of passing the actual variable.

Comment: @Turing85: The bug report says this: _"EXPECTED - The call on line 20 ("".equals(newString)) should evaluates to "false"."_ Surely that is not correct!? `newString` should have value `""`, since it should be created with the 0-arg `String` constructor. Did you mix up the "expected" and "actual" sections in the bug report? (Or am I confused?)